# Setting tor hidden service in /etc/hosts

Tags: onion-services, configuration, network-configuration, server-administration, server

ok so I wasn't receiving updates for drupal so I decided to go to /etc/hosts
and added my hostname like so

127.0.0.1  something.onion

I restarted tor and drupal now can receive updates again anyways does this cause any issues? Is it dangerous to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Should be fine. You're just affecting connections originating at your own machine. Whether it is safe to use drupal's autoupdater at all is something you have to ask yourself, of course.